# Django: роль атрибута в модуле

Tags: python, django, модули

```
from django.db import models

class Pages(models.Model):
       ...
```

Какую роль играет атрибут models.Module при создании модуля? Он наследует какие-то нужные методы (если да, то какой например)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Модели реализуются как подклассы django.db.models.Model.
В данном случае `models.Model` указывает что это модель, а не просто какой то класс.